# How can I ping a host with a Perl one-liner with Net::Ping?

Tags: perl

Trying to integrate the following Perl one-liner into a shell script. This code works within a Perl script but not as a one-liner executed from a shell script.

I've tried replacing `$host` with a real hostname with no luck.

```
#!/bin/ksh

hosts="host1 host2 host3"

PERL=/usr/bin/perl

# Check to see if hosts are accessible.
for host in $hosts
do
   #echo $host
   $PERL -e 'use Net::Ping; $timeout=5; $p=Net::Ping->new("icmp", $timeout) or die bye ; print "$host is alive \n" if $p->ping($host); $p->close;'
done
```

Comment: Why are you using perl instead of just `ping`?

Comment: I integrated this into an already written shell script that I do not care to port. This serves as a convenient, consistently fast (that is, it does not hang) one-liner that works across platforms.

Answer (score 11):

The single quotes in the shell stop the $host from being interpreted. So you can just stop and restart the single quotes as required:

```
perl -MNet::Ping -e 'if (Net::Ping->new("icmp", 5)->ping("'$host'")) {print "'$host' is alive\n"}'
```

Alternatively, you can pass the host in as a parameter - see the other answer.

Comment: Doh, just like with sed. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace `$host`:

```
$PERL -e 'use Net::Ping; $timeout=5; $p=Net::Ping->new("icmp", $timeout) or die bye ; print "$host is alive \n" if $p->ping($host); $p->close;'
```

with `$ARGV[0]`, the first command line argument:

```
$PERL -e 'use Net::Ping; $timeout=5; $p=Net::Ping->new("icmp", $timeout) or die bye ; print "$ARGV[0] is alive \n" if $p->ping($ARGV[0]); $p->close;' $host
```

Comment: I 'almost' thought of doing this but turned away. However, this gives me an additional option I can integrate into this script. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Perl, then use the Perl interpreter to run your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
use Net::Ping;
$timeout=5;
$p=Net::Ping->new("icmp", $timeout) or die bye ;
@hosts=qw/localhost 10.10.10.10/;
foreach my $host (@hosts) {
  print "$host is alive \n" if $p->ping($host);
}
$p->close;
```

Otherwise, you might as well use the `ping` command directly from the shell

```
#!/bin/bash
for hosts in host1 host2 host3
do
  if ping  ...... "$hosts"  >/dev/null  ;then
      .....
  fi 
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree --just use perl exclusively. I integrated this into an already written shell script that I do not care to port. This serves as  a convenient, consistently fast (that is, it does not hang) one-liner.